# Does Delerium stack with Supervirus?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

The Dark Knight Delerium skill puts a debuff on a mob that reduces that target's INT by 10%.  A Monk's Dragon Kick does the same.  I know these two buffs are exclusive, you cannot apply Delerium while Dragon Kick is on the mob.

But what about [Supervirus](http://www.ffxivinfo.com/class/arcanist.php?ability=supervirus)?

Supervirus reduces a target's STR, DEX, INT, and MND by 15%, and it *is* possible to put Supervirus on a mob that already has Dragon Kick/Delerium.

What is the total INT down for a mob with both Delerium and Supervirus?  Is it just the greater amount (15%) or does it stack?  And if it stacks, does it stack additively or multiplicatively?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the second half of your question but in all my experience in FFXIV as both DRK and SCH I have never had either delirium or virus cancel each other out. I will try and test this out tonight with my friends to see if I can figure this out, cause I am kind of curious now about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me and a few of my friends just ran some tests in game to test out this. Before I get to the details I will explain the process we went through.

To test this question we found a high level magic enemy that we could easily test on, for this we used the level 58 earth sprites outside of Idyllshire, while they are not level 60 they still served our purpose to test this. To test the damage we had our dark knight tank one of these mobs and collected the high and low values for all four of our cases which were as follows.

- **No Debuffs applied**
- **Delirium only applied**
- **Virus only applied**
- **Both Delirium and Virus applied**

After observing the high and low damage marks for all four of our cases I am able to calculate the percent decrease in damage in all of our situations. Okay on to the observations we obtained.

For an earth sprite casting stone 1 we calculated the following damage values:

- **No debuffs:** 390-430 damage per hit
- **Delirium only:** 350-390 damage per hit
- **Virus only:** 330-350 damage per hit
- **Delirium and Virus:** 298-322 damage per hit

And with these values we can calculate the percent decrease by comparing the base damage to the damage with each combination of debuffs. In my math I only compared our low damage values for each case.

For Delirium only when comparing the damage values we get about **10.26%** decrease in damage which is exactly the value of decrease we were expected for Delirium only. For the Virus only we get a damage increase of about **15.38%** which again is the value we are expecting for a Virus which is a 15% decrease in damage.

**And for the moment of truth.**

When comparing the combined combined debuff damages to the base damage we get about **23.59%** decrease in damage. This value proves two things, first **the two debuffs do indeed stack together**. The second discovery is that **delirium and virus do stack multiplicatively.**

Comment: Thanks for running these.  One point though is I think your test shows they stack multiplicatively instead of additively.  .9 x .85 comes out to a .765 damage output (so 23.5% reduction), which matches almost precisely with your 23.6% number.  The other reason my guess is multiplicatively is because defensive cooldowns stack multiplicatively (e.g. Shadowskin + Shadow Wall isn't 50% reduction).

Comment: Hmmm that would make a lot of sense I went with assumption since it was extremely difficult to get attack numbers for both debuffs because of the extremely short window for it to be active. I'll edit my post.